# Debugging in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i want to debug ROR without going through the effort of putting inspect method for every relevant object in the controller as well in the model.is there a better way as we have in *Java (Run time debugger using eclipse)*.i know that I can Use `Rails.logger` and also make use of rails Console(irb`).i am even aware of debugging/inspecting elements in erb/rb file.Still is there a **better,quick and reliable way to debug a Rails app**.

Comment: There are some console debuggers. RubyMine offers visual debugger (or so they say, I have never used it. Debug printing is usually enough for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this lines to your application's **Gemfile**

```
group :development do
  gem 'ruby-debug19'
end
```

then run cammand

```
 bundle install
```

add `debugger` within your controller or model method, stop the rails server and restart again. Whenever rails found word `debugger` it stops control at that point. You can easily debug your value or object. 
Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 3):

There is much better, see this [railscats](http://railscasts.com/episodes/402-better-errors-railspanel).

It presents two great gems, especially [Better Errors](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors)

Otherwise, you could use [pry](http://pry.github.com/) with rails, see this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails).

Comment: better_errors is hardly a debugger replacement. What if there's no error, and just a breakpoint?

Comment: you can also throw in a raise where you want the equivalent of a breakpoint when using better_errors.  I agree though, it's not a replacement.  Different people like different methods though

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `pry-rails`, `pry-debugger` and then use `binding.pry` method in your code and then while using your app you have Rails console available in rails server